# Validación de inputs creados desde jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, validación

Necesito validar los inputs creados en mis funciones `add` y `edit`. Lo he intentado con la función `validate` de jQuery, pero no funciona.

He intentado meter mi table dentro de un form, pero tampoco es la solución pues 
inserto una fila en la cual están los inputs y el botón que llama a la función guardar.

**fn_Add**

```js
function fn_Add() {

    $("#tblFactores tbody").prepend("<tr>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='form-upload input-sm' style='width: 100%'/></td>" +
        "<td class='text-center'><input type='checkbox' checked='checked'/></td>" +
        *"<td class='text-center'>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-info btn-circle save' href='javascript:;' title='Guardar' ><i  class='fa fa-save'></i></a>" +
        "<a class='btn btn-danger btn-circle cancel' href='javascript:;' title='Cancelar' ><i class='fa fa-ban'></i></a>" +
        "</td></tr>");*
};
```

**edito una fila**

```js
function fn_Edit(elem) {

    var par = $(elem).parent().parent();
    var tdnombre_factor = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdestado = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdbuttons = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var estado;

    tdnombre_factor.html("<input type='text' id='txtdescripcion' class='form-control input-sm' style='width: 100%' value='" + tdnombre_factor.html() + "'/>");
    estado = tdestado.children("i").hasClass("fa-square-o") ? "<input type='checkbox'/>" : "<input type='checkbox'  checked='checked'/>";
    tdestado.html(estado);
    tdbuttons.html('<a class="btn btn-primary btn-circle save"><i class="fa fa-save " title="Guardar"></i></a><a class="btn btn-danger btn-circle cancel" title="Cancelar"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>');
};
```

**Descripción**
[image: view]

**Código en JSP**

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="tblFactores">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdd" id="btnAdd"> Agregar</button>                            
    <thead>
        <tr>                                    
            <th>Factor</th>                                    
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <%
            List < Factor > listafactores = FactorNEG.Instancia().Listar();
            for (int i = 0; i < listafactores.size(); i++) {
                int tipo = listafactores.get(i).getCodigo();
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<td class='text-center'>" + listafactores.get(i).getDescripcion() + "</td>");
                if (listafactores.get(i).getEstado() == 1) {
                    out.println("<td class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-check-square-o'></i></td>");
                } else {
                    out.println("<td class='text-center'><i class='fa fa-square-o'></i></td>");
                }
            %> 
            <td class="text-center" data-id="<%=listafactores.get(i).getCodigo()%>" >
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle edit" title="Editar"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle remove " title="Eliminar"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <%
            }   
        %>
    </tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: Amigo, se ve que eres JAVERO ese código le quemaría los ojos a cualquier JS Developer decente, en fin vamos por partes.  Podrías publicar el código HTML después de que lo compila el JSP por favor?. Ya que al final de cuentas vamos a trabajar con el JS, ya sea que tu JSP cree cosas dinamicamente :)

Comment: esta seguro del html? osea el codigo que me muestra en el navegador? (si es asi, puede ser en un print de paltalla, porque sino seria demasiado engorroso pegarlo aqui )

Comment: Preguntas sobre cómo validar los campos, pero el código que incluyes no tiene absolutamente nada sobre validación. "_Lo he intentado con la función validate de jQuery, pero no funciona_", ¿cómo lo has intentado?¿cómo no funciona? (pega el código que intentaste y el error que obtuvieses).

Comment: Bueno intente hacer el mismo metodo de un form normal :
Estos pasos (pd : el codigo esta en diferentres prints de pantalla)
http://prntscr.com/cf8s5f
http://prntscr.com/cf8u29
http://prntscr.com/cf8udk
http://prntscr.com/cf8vsp
Cuando apreto el boton guardar se ejecuta sin darme la validacion de que me impida guardar sin texto.  
PD : Alguien me puede explicar como dar un salto de linea en los comentarios (de este foro)  y como insertar codigo en los comentarios. Ya lei la guia , pero igual no me sale :/

Comment: EStas en las mismas amigo, aun no le dices a Jquery Validate,  "CUAL es el formulario a validar y en que momento hacerlo".

Comment: igual, algo "fácil" es agregar la propiedad **required** a los input PERO como ya se ha mencionado, sin estar en un form no va a hacer algo, ni el validator de jQuery ni el atributo html5 required

Answer (score 0):

Hola yo utilizo el siguiente metodo para validar los campos del formulario

primero a cada uno de los inputs o etiquetas que contengan un valor les aisgno una clase que se llame required por ejemplo:

```
<form id = 'formid'>
    <input  type="text" class=" required" name="name" >
    <input  type="text" class=" required" name="direccion" >
</form>
```

despues tengo esta funcion que la llamo cuando voy a guardar los datos:

```
function validate(formId){
    var validation = document.getElementById(formId).querySelectorAll(".required");
    var flag = true;
    for(var j = 0 ; j<validation.length; j++ ){ 
        if(validation[j].value === "" || validation[j].value === "none"){
            validation[j].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000'; 
            flag = false;
        }   
    }
    return flag;
}
```

es muy simple

Comment: dale. lo probare, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tienes formas mas o menos elegantes de hacerlo. Una de ellas a bote pronto es que una vez que hagas click en guardar, llames a una función enviándole los campos necesarios pertenecientes a esa línea moviéndote por el DOM, recogerlos y a continuación enviarlos (lo suyo sería hacerlo con AJAX). Además por lo que veo utilizas datatables, que con *row().data()* obtienes cómodamente los valores en un array para tratarlos.

Otra opción es que generes un formulario en cada línea llamándolos algo como "prefijo-iddelínea, no sé si me explico:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < listafactores.size(); i++) {
                int tipo = listafactores.get(i).getCodigo();
                out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<form name='loquesea" + idXXX + "' action='...'>");
                out.println("<td class='text-center'>" + listafactores.get(i).getDescripcion() + "</td>");
                ....
                out.println("</form>")
                ....
```

Con la segunda solución lo tienes mas fácil a la hora de validarlos, pues si le añades el atributo *required* más el tipo adecuado ya tienes las de HTML5, si no igual que el primero debes hacerlo manualmente o con librería.